# How to setup the following different parameters of JANUS-WebRTC-GATEWAY?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, janus-gateway

I would like to know how to configure the different parameters of **JANUS-WebRTC-GATEWAY** that installed using **SNAP** (`sudo snap install janus-gateway`) on Ubuntu ???

```
JANUS_SERVER_ENDPOINT=
JANUS_SERVER_ADMIN_ENDPOINT=
JANUS_ADMIN_SECRET=
JANUS_API_SECRET=
JANUS_VIDEO_ROOM_SECRET=
```

*This is for setting up a project in the PHP Laravel Framework but I don't see resources anywhere on the internet that can help me set up these various JANUS settings and connect them to my PHP web application which requires these Janus settings before working.*

**Where are these different parameters located on my Linux Server ???**

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

let's break it in two parts: webserver config and janus config

**Webserver:**

JANUS_SERVER_ENDPOINT & JANUS_SERVER_ADMIN_ENDPOINT

are defined by you when you install & config your apache/nginx web server
see this: https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/deploy.html
it describes how to deploy Janus behind webserver

**Janus:**

once you install Janus on Ubuntu you will find a folder: /opt/janus/etc/janus/
with some config files, most likely you dont need to edit all of them, only the ones that you need to. You will understand what each file configs by its name.

To use this config files you first need to copy and rename by removing .sample from the end of the file name.
so in the config files you set:
JANUS_ADMIN_SECRET
JANUS_API_SECRET
JANUS_VIDEO_ROOM_SECRET (video rooms can be created dynamically, without using the videoroom config file, but if you know how many rooms you need you can tweak the config)

P.S. Janus docs are written, most likely, for developers who have PhD in everything. So if you don't understand it, i feel you. Struggled for a month to understand it.